# Addsubview not showing uiimageview

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I'm trying to put a uiimageview on a scrollview via addsubiew but nothing shows. This is the code in viewDidLoad:

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button"];
UIImageView *buttonImageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:buttonImage];
buttonImageview.frame = (CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=buttonImage.size};
[self.scrollView addSubview:buttonImageview];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong :( In my .h file, the line with the IBOutlet of the scrollview had the circle filled in, meaning it was hooked up. I put the cursor over it to see where but nothing showed up. I hooked it up again and it is now working.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you meant

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"]
```

;-)

Comment: I didn't put the extension so that it picks up button.png or button@2x.png.

Comment: @pedroremedios have you tried adding it to a non-scroll view?

Comment: yeah but speaking of reading the docs :) "On iOS 4 and later, if the file is in PNG format, it is not necessary to specify the .PNG filename extension. Prior to iOS 4, you must specify the filename extension."

Answer (score 0):

My ideas:
- be sure that the file indeed is in the compile resources. 
- check, by some NSLog, if the image is loading correctly, printing the CGSize of the image.
- be sure that the frame is being setup correctly

You do can call [UIImage imageNamed:@"button"], it looks for the correct retina or not image depending on the device

Answer (score 0):

Scrollview requires that you set a number of properties on it. In particular contentSize. You have not included the code in your original question where you allocate it and set it up, that is likely where the problem is. Without seeing it I can only presume, but you will have to do something like the following.  For example:

```
aScrollView.contentSize = sizeOfImage; // Have to set a size here related to your content.
// You should set these.
aScrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

[aScrollView addSubview:Your Image];

aScrollView.minimumZoomScale = .5;  // You will have to set some values for these
aScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;
aScrollView.zoomScale = 1;

[self.view addSubview:aScrollView];
```